# UML : including use cases of different users?

Tags: uml

Is it legal to draw up an include relationship between two use cases that are each associated with a different actor?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is legal, but I think it should not interpreted as @vainolo suggested.
Suppose this scenario
[image]

In this case `Actor X` has direct access to `Use Case A` and because `Use Case B` is included by `Use case A` Actor X also executed the behavior described in `Use CAse B`
But only `Actor Y` has direct access `Use Case B`.
`Actor A` only has indirect access through `Use Case A`

At least that is how I interpret it. The [UML specs](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/) will only tell you this is a valid UML syntax but will not say much about the meaning of such a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It's completely legal. What this means is that if the including use case calls the included use case, the actor that is connected to this use case is required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are there any sources of reference you can point to?

Comment: [www.uml-diagrams.org](www.uml-diagrams.org) is the best source for UML info on the net

Comment: A use case is not called since it's no function. You could say that the scenario of a use case is performed.